# Binary tree doesn't accept new node

Tags: c++, pointers, tree, binary-tree

```
int main(){
Node *root , *temp , *temp_before;
root = new Node(0 , NULL , NULL , NULL);
temp_before = root;
temp = temp_before->left;
temp = new Node(5 , NULL , NULL , NULL);
temp = root->left;
cout<<temp->val;
}
```

I have a struct named Node, first argument is int, the others are Node pointer. When I wanted to print root->left it didn't work, the program stopped when i run it. I don't know, maybe I am doing a really weird thing by expecting this to return something but what's the problem?

Comment: Where do you set a node in the tree to point to `temp`?

Comment: Uninitialized local non-static variables (like the one you have) have an *indeterminate* value until you initialize them. Using those uninitialized variable will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: point to the line where you set root->left to anything other than null

Comment: @pm100 temp_before = root;      temp = temp_before->left     temp = new Node(5, null , null , null );       i think this declares a value for root->left, am i wrong

Comment: There is also a memoryleak at temp=new node and directly under that you say temp=root->left

Comment: Please edit your post the definition (code) of `Node`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's have a look at the code line by line:

```
struct Node {
    int val;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
    Node* parent;
    Node(int value, Node* left, Node* right, Node* parent): val(value), left(left), right(right), parent(parent){}
};

void main() {
    Node *root, *temp, *temp_before;
    root = new Node(0, NULL, NULL, NULL); // root points to the newly allocated memory
    temp_before = root; //temp_before also points to that memory
    temp = temp_before->left; // temp points to the left of root, which is null
    // NOTE: at this point, temp isn't connected to the tree, even if you allocate memory with it.
    // You only have pointers ("handles") for those memory blocks but you haven't combined them together yet.
    temp = new Node(5, NULL, NULL, NULL); // This allocated memory for the memory address pointed by temp
    // temp = root->left; //error
    root->left = temp; //correct one
    // Now root->left points to the memory block you allocated with temp
}
```

When you allocate memory using pointers, your pointer points only to that memory block. They won't become a connected structure unless you manually connect them together.

That was what you were trying to do but in the wrong way. Think of it like this: When you allocate memory, the Operating System gives you a space from main memory. It does it by giving you a "reference" to that memory block so that you can use that memory block however you want. That's why pointers are also referred to as "handles" because they are your way of interacting with memory blocks.

In the erronous line, you were overriding your handle to the memory you just allocated. When you do it, you lose your access to that memory block until the end of program's execution. These overrides are called "memory leaks" because that block of memory is something you asked but forgot about.

When you execute `temp = root->left;`, it overrides your pointer with another pointer (in this case, one that points to `NULL`) and when you try to print it, it gives you an error called `null pointer exception`, which from the name you can clearly see the problem :)

When you overcomplicate the thing you are trying to do, these mistakes happen
tend to happen, especially if you are inexperienced with memory. The way you can simplify this code is:

```
void main() {
    Node* root = new Node(0, NULL, NULL, NULL); // Allocate root
    root->left = new Node(5, NULL, NULL, NULL); // This line means "add a new node to the left of my root"

    std::cout << root->val << std::endl;
    std::cout << root->left->val << std::endl;
}
```

If you struggle with above implementation, think of it like this:

```
Node* temp = new Node(5, NULL, NULL, NULL);
root->left = temp;
```

This code is the same as the code in `main` function. Think of it like this: You are allocating a memory block and access it using handle `temp`. After that, you are **assigning** that handle's information to the left node pointer of your root. This way, you can access the same memory block through `root->left` even if you don't have access to `temp` anymore.

The code below is how you were thinking about it. Try to think about the difference between those two and once you figure it out, pointers will make more sense:

```
Node* temp = root->left;
temp = new Node(5, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: I know i shouldn't write "thanks" in the comments at stack overflow but really thanks for this far-reaching answer! This was comletely what i was searching for. I was having problems about pointers at the same time and this helped for it too, and thank you very much for your time you gave for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things. You will need to check if your node is equal to null. You also should be updating what you are outputting.

```
node = root;
while (node != null) 
{
    count << node;
    node = node->left;

}
```

Comment: if node->left equals to null, how should i transport node to node->left?

Comment: Set node to the head initially and then traverse. I updated my answer @TahaSümer